# How shall we show the surface integral approaches a limit (or does not blow up) at a field point near $S'$

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, mathematical-physics, charge, singularities

Consider the electric field due to volume charge distribution in volume $V'$:

$\mathbf{E}=\displaystyle \int_{V'} \rho' \dfrac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^3} dV'$

The integrand blows up at a field point $P \in V'$. But the integral remains finite. This can be shown by choosing $P$ as the center of our Cartesian coordinate system and switching to spherical coordinate system.

Now consider the electric field due to surface charge distribution in surface $S'$:

$\mathbf{E}=\displaystyle \int_{S'} \sigma' \dfrac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^3} dS'$

At a field point $P \in S'$, it can be shown using Gaussian pillbox argument that there is a discontinuity of $4\pi \sigma'$ in the field $\mathbf{E}$ and hence the field is undefined at a point $P \in S'$.

Now as $P$ gets closer and closer to the surface, the integrand blows up. **Now how shall we show that the integral doesn't blow up (or approaches a limit)?**

Conditions:

1. $\sigma'$ is nowhere infinite
2. $S'$ is a closed and bounded surface (finite surface)

Comment: Rephrasing your question: are you trying to prove that a function that is measurable *almost everywhere* can still have a well defined surface integral? If so, this is a well studied field of complex analysis and residuals theorems and the answer lies in there (totally independent of this application to the electric field).

Comment: @gented: Then how did people (eg: Poisson, Maxwell,etc) dealt with it before the birth of complex analysis?

Comment: Do you mean how they dealt with proving that it still converges or how they calculated it? For the former I don't know for sure but I believe they just didn't care :)...for the latter you can just practically integrate it by using the definition of surface integral and Dini's theorem (which reduces everything to standard Riemann integrals).

Comment: I see... So could it be that most of electromagnetism became rigorous after the introduction of these advanced topics (after Maxwell's death)?

Comment: That would be my guess but I must say I know very little on the historical details (so you may post the question on "history of mathematics" perhaps or wait for someone else to add a thorough answer).

Comment: @gented is that what OP wants? I read this question as wanting to know why $\vec{E}$ doesn't blow up arbitrarily close to a charged surface. Which is intuitively clear but my analysis skills aren't up to proving. Plus pathological surfaces might exist I suppose (I have no idea what happens arbitrarily close to the surface of a uniformly charged Koch snowflake).

Comment: @jacob1729 What does it mean that a vector field blows up close to a charged surface? Then the question should be: *"why is the electric field of a closed surface infinite?"* which has nothing to do with integrals and all the rest.

Comment: @gented for a vector field to 'blow up' I mean that it's magnitude becomes infinite. OP writes an integral solution for $\vec{E}$ and states that the integrand 'blows up' for contributions coming from the surface near the field point. But unless OP clarifies I have no interest in debating what their post means.

Comment: Relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/450426/

Comment: @jacob: it is exactly as you say. Your interpretation of my post is correct

Comment: @jacob1729 I don't understand why anything would blow up on a closed surface - *unless* the field is non-measurable there, which is what I address in the first place. And if the problem is that the electric potential is ill-defined in zero, then this is a whole different story and the question is really ill-posed. "Why is the electric field not defined in zero?" should be the actual question (to which there are many answers on this platform already).